Google Sheets Extending Column Length
Some columns that have a lot of text require extending them in order to see all of the information.
What can I do to have multiple columns show all of the text instead of individually extending each column?
I've tried looking into the format section but couldn't find a solution. I'm guessing there should be an option somewhere in the tools menu.

Sadly, I don't think there is any way to auto resize column width as you are adding data. Your best options are to format a column with text wrapping or double click the right header border to scale-to-fit.
